# Data in custom admin module not showing up

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, adminhtml

I have followed exact steps given in the below magento guide link but no data is showing in the custom php page.

[Magento Guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/example-module-adminpage.html)

My codes are :

> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\BBC\ProdAdmin\composer.jason

```
{"name": "bbc/ProdAdmin",
  "description": "A module that creates a page in the Magento admin area",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.6.0|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "BBC\\ProdAdmin\\": ""
    }
  }}
```

> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\BBC\ProdAdmin\registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'BBC_ProdAdmin',
    __DIR__
);
```

> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\BBC\ProdAdmin\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="BBC_ProdAdmin" setup_version="1.0.0">
  </module>
</config>
```

> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\BBC\ProdAdmin\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
      <add id="BBC_ProdAdmin::greetings" title="Prod Admin Panel" translate="title" module="BBC_ProdAdmin" parent="Magento_Backend::content" sortOrder="50" dependsOnModule="BBC_ProdAdmin" resource="BBC_ProdAdmin::greetings"/>
      <add id="BBC_ProdAdmin::greetings_helloworld" title="Admin Access" translate="title" module="BBC_ProdAdmin" parent="BBC_ProdAdmin::greetings" sortOrder="10" dependsOnModule="BBC_ProdAdmin" action="prodadmin/ProdAdminControl" resource="BBC_ProdAdmin::greetings"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\BBC\ProdAdmin\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
  <router id="admin">
      <route id="prodadmin" frontName="prodadmin">
          <module name="BBC_ProdAdmin"/>
      </route>
  </router>
```

> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\BBC\ProdAdmin\Controller\Adminhtml\ProdAdminControl\Index.php

```
<?php namespace BBC\ProdAdmin\Controller\Adminhtml\ProdAdminControl;

  class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
  {
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
    */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
         parent::__construct($context);
         $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Load the page defined in view/adminhtml/layout/exampleadminnewpage_helloworld_index.xml
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
         return  $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
  }
?>
```

> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\BBC\ProdAdmin\view\adminhtml\layout\ProdAdmin_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>
            Product Admin Access
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="BBC_ProdAdmin::AdminAccess.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\BBC\ProdAdmin\view\adminhtml\templates\AdminAccess.phtml

```
  <p>Hello World!</p>
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: I have updated your mistake check my answer.

Comment: if my answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark, hit that tickmark for right answer that will help future readers.

Comment: Update file name composer.json instead of composer.jason and check.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout looks wrong.

Try below:

> ../adminhtml/layout/prodadmin_prodadmincontrol_index.xml

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="BBC\ProdAdmin\Block\Adminhtml\Test" name="test" template="AdminAccess.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

> ../Block/Adminhtml/Test.php

```
namespace BBC\ProdAdmin\Block\Adminhtml;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link
{
  // Your Functions
}
```

> ../templates/AdminAccess.phtml

```
<?php  echo "Today is " . date("Y/m/d") . "<br>"; ?>
```

Comment: Should I recompile magento

Comment: Yes, Execute `setup:upgrade` from root of Magento.

Comment: I got Below error

Comment: @neelavbarai, As i said above execute `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` . than `cache:clean` than check.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong.

I have just created the same module and its working for me.

1. `composer.json`, `registration.php`, `etc/module.xml`, `etc\adminhtml\routes.xml` and `Controller\Adminhtml\ProdAdminControl\Index.php` file looks okay.

I have update below the files.

> BBC/ProdAdmin/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
      <add id="BBC_ProdAdmin::greetings" title="Prod Admin Panel" translate="title" module="BBC_ProdAdmin" parent="Magento_Backend::content" sortOrder="50" dependsOnModule="BBC_ProdAdmin" resource="BBC_ProdAdmin::greetings"/>
      <add id="BBC_ProdAdmin::greetings_helloworld" title="Admin Access" translate="title" module="BBC_ProdAdmin" parent="BBC_ProdAdmin::greetings" sortOrder="10" dependsOnModule="BBC_ProdAdmin" action="prodadmin/prodadmincontrol" resource="BBC_ProdAdmin::greetings"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

> BBC/ProdAdmin/view/adminhtml/layout/prodadmin_prodadmincontrol_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>
            Product Admin Access
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="BBC_ProdAdmin::adminaccess.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> BBC/ProdAdmin/view/adminhtml/templates/adminaccess.phtml

`AdminAccess.phtml` replace with `adminaccess.phtml`

> php bin/magento cach:flush

Now your module is working.